# adding service worker to reactjs app

Tags: reactjs, offline, offline-caching, service-worker

I'm about the create a small single page reactjs app that fetches data from 3rd API (let's say  youtube videos, so those will be displayed). So I don't need any backend at all, but I'd like to make it offline first with service workers, so if there is no connection it will still display some cached data by default. For this I will use service workers, but don't really know if I have to add any other library or I can just use it right away.

Could somebody tell me what the best way is to implement this small offline-first react app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're looking for a self-contained starting point, https://github.com/localnerve/react-pwa-reference looks promising.

If you're looking for a functional web app to draw some inspiration from, there's https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache/tree/master/app-shell-demo, which fetches information from the iFixit API, and is conceptually similar to a web app that would fetch information from the YouTube API.

(Just note that YouTube embedded video playback won't work offline, even with service workers.)